# Node.js oauth2 authenticantion

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I need to authenticate to a web application (not google, not facebook, not twitter) using Oauth2.

Most of the code that i have found and tried out there are for Google, Twitter, Facebook.

I have the end points, i have the client key and secret, i just do not know how to connect to it.

So how do I authenticate using Oauth2 from an application that is not Google, FB, Twitter, etc?

If you can point me to some code examples, i would really appreciate it...

EDIT: Using passport code below, but not clear now to make it work. If i execute this, it doesnt fire back the code under http.createserver...

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
var http = require('http');


passport.use('provider', new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://api.tradegecko.com/oauth/authorize',
    tokenURL: 'https://api.tradegecko.com/oauth/token',
    clientID: '123',
    clientSecret: '456',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/'
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log('Check 1...')
  }
));

passport.authenticate('provider');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log('I have no idae what im doing2...')
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end();

  }).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Did you try http://passportjs.org/guide/oauth/ ?

Comment: I did, and sorry, perhaps this is me being a noob:

Comment: Where exactly does this go? app.js?

Comment: This one: 
var passport = require('passport')
  , OAuthStrategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuthStrategy;
passport.use('provider', new OAuthStrategy({
    requestTokenURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/request_token',
    accessTokenURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/access_token',
    userAuthorizationURL: 'https://www.provider.com/oauth/authorize',
    consumerKey: '',
    consumerSecret: ''
    callbackURL: ''
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    User.findOrCreate(..., function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  }
));

Comment: That depends on the directory and file structure. If you are on Express, then yes you can put it in app.js. That callback to newOAuthStrategy - it can be different in your case. I guess findOrCreate is a mongoose function - the author is just storing the tokens in mongodb for later usage

Comment: See above, i edited the code...

Comment: you need to hit the url localhost:8080 to see the logs in the console. you wrote the cosole.log statements inside the callback of createserver. that callback will only be executed when a request comes in. the 'req' variable will hold all the information regarding the request.. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLndbWGuLoHeaqf-IS7Ni0d6pIxLfLUynV

Comment: Wow, thanks for that URL! Have to go through it...
Ok, i'm making much more progress, i did it the express route, and now i am able to almost authenticate. The issue now is that the endpoint is reporting The redirect uri included is not valid.
I'm guessing localhost is not a valid response? If it tries to connect to localhost from their end, it leads nowhere...
Does my app need to be publicly accesible?